# How can I capture events from Flirc USB (HID Device) using Python (on Windows)?

Tags: python, hid

My goal is simple. It is to use a FLIRC USB device connected to my windows laptop. I then want to point an Infrared remote control to it and press each button and have a Python script listen for each time a button is pressed on the remote i.e listen for any event on the FLIRC USB.

So far I understand that that the FLIRC USB device is a HID device. I am able to grab the vendor ID and product ID of the HID device using the following script using the pywinusb module:

```
import pywinusb.hid as hid

all_devices = hid.find_all_hid_devices()

flirc_hid_devices = []

for device in all_devices:
    if "flirc.tv" in str(device):
        flirc_hid_devices.append(str(device))

print(flirc_hid_devices[0])
```

The good thing is that I am able to identify the FLIRC USB's vendor and product ID (as it is a HID device).

Where I am stuck is I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://github.com/rene-aguirre/pywinusb/blob/master/examples/raw_data.py ?

Comment: @AKX Yes I have tried exactly that but nothing shows up on any remote control key presses.